# How transfer data from Google Cloud Storage to Biq Query in partitioned and clustered table?

Tags: google-bigquery, hierarchical-clustering, data-transfer

In first time,I created a empty table with partition and cluster. After that, I would like to configure data transfere service to fill my table from Google Cloud Storage.But when I configure the transfer, I didn't see a parameter field which allows to choose the cluster field.

I tried to do the same thing without the cluster and I can fill my table easily.

Big query error when I ran the transfer:

```
Failed to start job for table matable$20190701 with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Incompatible table partitioning specification. Destination table exists with partitioning specification interval(type:DAY,field:) clustering(string_field_15), but transfer target partitioning specification is interval(type:DAY,field:). Please retry after updating either the destination table or the transfer partitioning specification.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define the table you specify the partitioning and clustering columns. That's everything you need to do.

When you load the data (from CLI or UI) from GCS BigQuery automatically partition and cluster the data.

If you can give more detail of how you create the table and set up the transfer would be helpful to provide a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time.
Of course :

[empty table configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7gZZ.png)

[transfer configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ted5.png)

I success to transfer datat without cluster but, when I add a cluster in my empty table,the trasnfer fails.